# Does Freemarker honor MethodDescriptors?

Tags: java, javabeans, freemarker

(Background: I've been working with Java beans for somewhere around 18 years off and on; I've been working with Freemarker for a week or two.  :-))

I have a hand-tooled `BeanInfo` that represents the properties of a class that does not follow the "ordinary" (but obviously arbitrary) `get`/`set`-style of method naming.

Semantically, for a Java bean property named `x`, you would call a method named, simply, `x()` on this class.

So my `BeanInfo` implementation (which Freemarker is finding and loading) implements this pattern.  Fine.

The class in question actually has a method called `target()`, which returns a certain object (let's call it `Target` here), and which is represented by a `PropertyDescriptor` whose name is `target` and whose `readMethod` is that method.  Fine.

In my Freemarker template, if I do this:

```
theObject.target
```

...I get an error saying that `target`, effectively is a method, not a property, suggesting that my `PropertyDescriptor`, though technically findable, is not being consulted.  If I change this instead to:

```
theObject.target()
```

...then everything works.  The `target()` method, in other words, seems to be being seen by Freemarker as a method—it's like Freemarker is not "getting through" to the `PropertyDescriptor` which would otherwise tell it that this is actually the "read method" of a Java bean property.

I tried editing my `BeanInfo` to return an empty list of `MethodDescriptors`, thinking that perhaps that was the problem: if you return `null` from a particular method in `BeanInfo` then the `Introspector` does low-level introspection for that thing.  And `null` is the default.  So if you return `null` from `BeanInfo#getMethodDescriptors()`, `Introspector` will presumably find all the public methods in your class and create `MethodDescriptor`s for them.

Anyway, so I returned an empty list of `MethodDescriptor`s, hoping that I could force Freemarker into not "seeing" `target` as a method, but as a Java beans property ("falling through" to my `BeanInfo`'s `PropertyDescriptor` as mentioned above).  This didn't work.

In short, how can I make my:

```
someObject.target
```

...incantation access my property descriptor, not the `target()` method?

Comment: It does look like the [`MethodAppearanceFineTuner`](http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/ext/beans/MethodAppearanceFineTuner.html) class may be able to help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As FreeMarker uses `java.beans.Introspector` to discover bean properties and actions, it does honor the content of `BeanInfo`. Problem is, in your case that will return `PropertyDescriptor`-s and `MethodDescriptor`-s with clashing names. As the template language doesn't have a separate namespace for properties and methods, one has to shadow the other. By default, methods shadow  properties (which is not very practical nowadays, as fluent API-s often have methods like `Foo foo()` instead of `Foo getFoo()`). You can change that by setting the `methodAppearanceFineTuner` property of the `DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder` to a `MethodAppearanceFineTurner` object that simply always calls `decision.setMethodShadowsProperty(false)`.